# how to create this cover page?

Tags: covers

How could I create a cover page in a report as follows?

[image]

Especially I would like to know how to create this grey and red area.

Comment: You could use TikZ

Comment: could you help me with the code?

Comment: You have to redefine the `\maketitle` macro (using `\renewcommand`). TikZ may help you to make the grey and red area, as you can refer to the `current page` node to position a colored rectangular frame. I suggest you to provide a MWE, so that we can help you on detailed points, rather to do all the job for you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope that the following helps you get started. Please provide more details if you want something more help.

This is my MWE using `KOMA Script`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrpage2,scrextend}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\author{Name A. Surname}
\title{%
    \textcolor{BrickRed}{Journal of the} \vspace{1em}\\
Stackexchange \LaTeX users of the world wide web}

% This part depends on your actual environment, Here I am using KOMA script
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        % Gray boundary
        \node (left) at (current page.west)
              [rectangle, fill=gray, inner sep=0pt, anchor = west,
               minimum width=4cm, minimum height=1\paperheight]{};
        % Red boundary
        \node (bottom) at (current page.south)
              [rectangle, fill=BrickRed, inner sep=0 pt, anchor=south,
               minimum width=1\paperwidth, minimum height=0.5cm]{};

        % Some additional stuff:
        \node [yshift=\paperheight/3] (middle) at (current page.south)
              [rectangle, fill=Green, inner sep=0pt, anchor=north west,
               minimum height=3cm, minimum width=0.25\paperwidth]{};
        \node [yshift=\paperheight/3] (middle) at (current page.south)
              [rectangle, fill=BrickRed, inner sep=0pt, anchor=north east,
               minimum height=3cm, minimum width=0.25\paperwidth]{};
        \node [yshift=\paperheight/3] (middle) at (current page.south)
              [rectangle, fill=Goldenrod, inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west,
               minimum height=3cm, minimum width=0.25\paperwidth]{};
        \node [yshift=\paperheight/3] (middle) at (current page.south)
              [rectangle, fill=RoyalBlue, inner sep=0pt, anchor=south east,
               minimum height=3cm, minimum width=0.25\paperwidth]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \parindent0pt

    \begin{addmargin}{4em}
        \vspace{4cm}
        {\huge\usekomafont{title} \@title}

        \vspace{2cm}
        {\usekomafont{disposition}\Large \@author}
    \end{addmargin}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Start from the [erdc](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/erdc/) class.

[image]

It offers a cover page almost identical to what you are looking for. Once you have a working version post the code in a MWE if you need assistance.